# Rails number_to_currency delete trailing zeroes right of decimal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, number-to-currency

I have a dynamically generated table that multiplies price * qty.  Some of the prices are in partial cents. For example

if the price of an item is 0.0375 I can display that in my table as

```
number_to_currency(0.0375,:precision => 4)
=> $0.0375
```

but on quantities where the price is a standard 2 decimal number I get

```
number_to_currency(33.95,:precision => 4)
  => $39.9500
```

I need a way to trim the trailing zeroes of a decimal value.  Keep in mind that the output is in a Model.each block so I'm uncertain I can modify the precision parameter conditionally.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try to specify `strip_insignificant_zeros` option:

```
number_to_currency(33.95, precision: 4, strip_insignificant_zeros: true)
```

It should remove zeros after decimal separator. [Here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e6f9468e221999e5ea8342f8e72578e1f0a0ec09/activesupport/lib/active_support/number_helper/number_converter.rb#L31) is description of this option.

Comment: Thank you!  This answer met my requirements since number_to_currency is inside a loop.

Answer (score 1):

The default for this method is 2. So you simply need

`number_to_currency(33.95)`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_currency

Answer (score 0):

```
number_to_currency(33.95,:precision => 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `number_to_currency` returns a String, you can use `.remove(/0+$/)` to remove any trailing zeros:

```
number_to_currency(33.95,:precision => 4).remove(/0+$/)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `round` before `number_to_currency`:

```
number_to_currency(33.95.round(4)) # $33.95
number_to_currency(0.0375.round(4)) # $0.0375
```